# Smoking or to smoke costs a lot of money

Tags: grammar

What is the correct way to say the following sentence:

> Smoking costs a lot of money.

or

> To smoke costs a lot of money.

From what I have read I use the "-ing" form for something that I don't do anymore and the "to" form for something that I just stopped doing for a while. But I can't figure this one out.

Comment: I could start smoking tomorrow. Or I could start smoking twice as much tomorrow. That's the -ing form right there, and it's not talking about something that I don't do anymore, it's talking about something that I haven't even started yet. What you heard is wrong. It is not a rule of English.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: True, but so what? _To smoke costs a lot of money_ is not common, but to my ear it is perfectly grammatical.  In _To err is human_, the infinitive _To err_ is the subject.

Comment: @ColinFine, It sounds rather strange to me. And I don't think anyone would say it that way. (but I don't think any native speaker would use "To smoke" there. - *From your answer*).

Comment: It would sound fine in a different order: *It costs a lot of money to smoke.*

Answer (score 1):

"To smoke costs a lot of money" is similar in form to the famous J M Barrie quote from the novel Peter Pan ["To die will be an awfully big adventure"](http://theowlskull.blogspot.com/2013/02/to-die-will-be-awfully-big-adventure.html). This is rather dated and somewhat formal but is perfectly good English.

Having said that "To smoke costs a lot of money" does not sound natural in the contemporary context, it would be more normal to say "It costs a lot of money to smoke" or, as you say "Smoking costs a lot of money"

In his answer Colin Fine says that he does not think that any native speaker would use "To smoke" in that context but he cannot say why. I belive that "To smoke costs a lot of money" sounds odd because it is a mixture of slightly dated and formal English and modern casual English since "a lot of money" is colloquial and informal. "To smoke is expensive" does not sound so odd because both parts of the sentence are formal.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, but I don't think any native speaker would use "To smoke" there.

I'm not sure why this is.

**Edit**: people are questioning my sense that the *to smoke* form would ever be used.

The NoW corpus gives me (a very few) examples of this structure

> But to go without food is far more fatal.

They're rare, but that example seems completely natural to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the latter be 'To smoke, it costs a lot of money'?

Comment: That's also possible, but a different structure. I've only come up with the (rather old) _To err is human_ so far, but I'm sure there are other examples with a "to" infinitive as the subject.

Comment: But I'm not sure how that structure is being equated with the 'to err is human' structure. I find the proverb's structure similar to the form in my first comment.

Comment: Also, the more I perpend on the older structure, the more I think it's ambiguous. For example, the sentence could be the middle of a bigger sentence, changing the meaning. 'Marijuana, to smoke, costs a lot of money'. This introduction changes the meaning of the sentence. But with the inclusion of 'it', it makes sure that there's no tergiversation and the subject remains smoking and not Marijuana.

Comment: The proverb's form is precisely equivalent to my example: the "To" infinitive is the subject of the sentence. Your paraphrase has a completely different structure.

Comment: Okay....and what about the ambiguity it introduces? I don't think it's grammatical because it isn't complete.

Comment: What ambiguity? What isn't complete?

Comment: @NoamanAli “Marijuana, to smoke, costs a lot of money” isn’t a sentence at all – it doesn’t have any meaningful structure. “To smoke marijuana costs a lot of money” is a sentence. There is no need to introduce any _it_ and change the structure of the sentence. There is no ambiguity in the original sentence. It is a complete sentence, it is grammatical, it is unambiguous, and it makes sense.

Comment: To say that sentences can’t start with infinitives is ridiculous. :)

Comment: @NoamanAli You’re the one claiming that a straightforward sentence is ungrammatical with nothing to back up your claim. My corroboration (apart from _CGEL_) is the other native English speakers here who agree that it is grammatical. What is _your_ corroboration that an infinitive can be used as a parenthetical inserted between subject and verb in a matrix clause?

Comment: @NoamanAli Just in case the intent didn’t come through: my previous comment was intended as an example of a sentence starting with an infinitive. No disrespect intended.

Comment: @Lawrence Yeah, okay. I was just asking a question. The platform hasn't been the kindest to me ever since I've been here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry, not saying that it's nonsense. I'm just saying that people here tell me answers without corroboration are nonsense.

Comment: @NoamanAli Stack Exchange can be pretty tough sometimes, but if you stick around, you also get to make some friends. My "To say ..." comment was really friendly bantering with Colin regarding his answer and what seemed to be a suggestion that it's rare to find sentences starting with infinitives. I could have chosen a less inflammatory example, though, so please accept my apologies.

Comment: @Lawrence Nothing to it. I should probably stop running into umbrage every single time. But this website is exceptional. One of a kind. I'm grateful for the knowledge I've gained from it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither seems particularly idiomatic to me (USA).

I would expect to hear:

*Smoking is an expensive habit.*